# php search engine script

Tags: php, mysql, search

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
$search = $_GET ['search'];
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "gokul");
mysql_select_db("search123");
$query    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%'");
$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($foundnum == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.</br></br>1.
Try more general words. for example: If you want to search 'how to create a website' 
then use general keyword like 'create' 'website'</br>2. Try different words with similar
 meaning</br>3. Please check your spelling<br/>4.PLEASE DON'T USE SPACES";
}
else {
    echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    {
        $title = $runrows ['title'];
        $desc  = $runrows ['description'];
        $url   = $runrows ['url'];
        echo "<a href=$row[url]>$row[name]</a><br><font color=green>$row[url]</font><br>$row[desc]<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

This is my search engine script. This script only show one result. How to change it to show multy results using php

Comment: you need to add loop to print your results. i.e. `while`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change to:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $title = $runrows ['title'];
$desc = $runrows ['description'];
$url = $runrows ['url'];
echo "<a href=$row[url]>$row[name]</a><br><font color=green>$row[url]</font><br>$row[desc]<br/>";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more explanation for Elen's (correct) answer. mysql_fetch_assoc() fetches one record from the resultset. You can call it repeatedly to get each record in turn. Once you have fetched the last record "$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)" will fail. Therefore you can use that expression in your *while* loop to get each row and stop when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Here `mysql_fetch_assoc` you are just fetching the results, not looping them.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Use a `foreach()` or any loop method to get more results.