# php mysql search engine not finding results

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I am trying to make simple search engine. My problem is every code I am trying is bringing me same result "Found 0 results." My database is populated and when I put my SQL query into it, it gives me back result I look for.
I tried this code as well from stackoverflow [php search engine script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927591/php-search-engine-script) that did bring back 1 result for person asking that question and all I am getting is message "Sorry, there are no matching result". To write this code I followed youtube tutorial by phpacademy step by step and again same thing happened. I read all the comments under the tutorial to see if anyone came across same problem but it did work fine for everyone. I have no idea what I am doing wrong and would really appreciate if someone could help me.

That is form from my html file:

```
<body>
<form action="eatsearch.php" method="get">
    <label>
        Search
        <input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder = "Type to search..">
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Search">
```

and this is my php:

```
    <?php
require_once('config.php');

if(isset($_GET['keywords'])) {

    $keywords = $connect->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);

    $query = $connect->query("SELECT rname, tel, url, food 
    FROM general WHERE food LIKE '%{keywords}%'");

?>

    <div class="result-count">
        Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results.
    </div>

<?php

    if($query->num_rows) {
        while($result = $query->fetch_object()) {
?>

        <div class = "result">
            <a href="#"><?php echo $result->rname;?></a>
        </div>
<?php

        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keywords without $? 
Put a $keywords

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
$query = $connect->query("SELECT rname, tel, url, food FROM general WHERE food LIKE '%{keywords}%'");
```

It should be:

```
$query = $connect->query("SELECT rname, tel, url, food 
    FROM general WHERE food LIKE '%{$keywords}%'");
```

You forgot your `$` sign in front of the `keywords` variable.

Comment: Thank You. It worked. I have big problem with spelling and forgeting stuff like that. Need to work on it. Thanks again

Comment: I tried but it says I need 15 reputation for it, sorry