# Php how to get search engine working with tags and LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a search engine for my gallery website. I have the following code but it's only showing 1 result when there are 6 to be had:

```
<form action="?" method="get" id="form_search" name="search" class="search_form">
<input type="text" name="search_details" id="search_field"/><input type="submit" value="Search" name="search_field" form="form_search">
</form>



<?php

$tags = '%'.$_GET['search_details'].'%';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT rowid, tags FROM " . $username . " WHERE 
tags LIKE ? AND sort=?");       
$stmt->bind_param("si", $tags, $sort);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $arr[] = $row;
}
$stmt->close();

?>
```

The search engine seems to 'almost' work.

The 6 to be had each have the word "Downloads" in their tag records. The tags themselves are separated by commas only. But the search engine only seems to display 1 record. Also whilst searching another term, it displays 24 of 26 records. I'm assuming there's something wrong with the wildcard statement.

There's a foreach loop that follows in my code so the problem is different from the problem posted on this page: [php search engine script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927591/php-search-engine-script)

How do I get the correct number of records to be displayed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*the search engine only seems to display 1 record - The tags themselves are separated by commas only.*" if they're in one field separated by comma then there is only one result unless you split them by the comma

Comment: The "Downloads" tag appears in 6 different records, not 1 record (if thats what you mean by "field").

Comment: You stated "*The tags themselves are separated by commas only.*"

Comment: Show us an example of the contects of a `tags` column from your database

Comment: All of the following are in a simple tags record: Album 1,Album 2,Album 3,Downloads